# Perspective projection bends

Tags: projection, raytracing, perspective, perspectivecamera

I'm trying t create a raytracer and got some problems with the Perspective projection, as you can see in the picture below. To me it appears like it has curves, i.e. like surface of the viewingplane would be bend. 
Anybody any ideas or could help me?

Here is my main class

```
import entity.Image;
import primitives.Mesh;
import projection.Perspective1;
import projection.Projection;
import sampler.JitteredSample;
import sampler.Sampler;
import scene.Camera;
import scene.Lightning;
import scene.Lights;
import scene.World;
import scene.lightning.Ambient;
import scene.lightning.Parallel;
import scene.lightning.PointLight;
import tracer.Tracer;
import xmlReader.XmlReader;

public class Engine {


public static World world;
public static Image image;
public static Tracer Tracer;
public static Lights lights;
public static Camera camera;
public static Sampler sampler;
public static Projection projection;
public static Lightning lightning;
public static Mesh mesh;

public static void main(String[] args){

        //Create Engine Objects
        camera = new Camera(xmlReader.getCamera(source)); System.out.println("Create Camera");
        lights = new Lights(xmlReader.getLight(source)); System.out.println("Create Lights");
        world = new World(camera.getHoriziontalResolution(), camera.getVerticalResolution(), 1, source); System.out.println("Create World");
        image = new Image(xmlReader.getOutputFile(source)); System.out.println("Create Image File");
        Tracer = new Tracer();System.out.println("Create Tracer");
        sampler = new JitteredSample(4);System.out.println("Create Sampler");
        projection = new Perspective1();System.out.println("Create Projection");


    //start tracing time
    System.out.println("\n Start Tracing ... \n");
    start = System.nanoTime();
    //Start tracing
    for (int x = 0; x<world.viewplane.width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y<world.viewplane.height; y++){
            if (!black)
                Tracer.trace(x, y, source);
        }
    }


    //Save image as png
    image.write("PNG");
    //Stop tracing time
    end = System.nanoTime();
    //get results
    System.out.println("\n" + "Render Time: " + (end-start)/1000000000.F+ "\n");
    if (!black)
        System.out.println("Saved to: " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + xmlReader.getOutputFile(source));
    else
        System.out.println("Saved to: " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "example0.png");
}
```

}

```
import engine.Engine;
import entity.Colara;
import entity.Point2D;
import entity.Point3D;
import entity.Ray;
import entity.Vector3D;
import primitives.Sphere;
import primitives.Triangle;
import scene.Lightning;
import scene.lightning.Ambient;

public class Tracer {

public void trace(int x, int y, String source){
    Colara color = Engine.world.background;
    boolean hit = false;
    Ray ray;

    //Find Color of each Pixel/(samples*samples)
    for (int row = 0; row < Engine.sampler.samples; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < Engine.sampler.samples; col++){
            //Point to write on in the image
            Point2D point = Engine.sampler.sample(row,col,x,y);
            //Ray to find something. Depends on Projection
            ray = Engine.projection.createRay(point);

            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            Colara tempColor = new Colara();

            //For every Object          
            for(int i = 0; i<Engine.world.objects.size(); i++){
                //Hit Object with ray
                double temp = Engine.world.objects.get(i).hit(ray);
                /*
                Shadow Rays
                */
                //If hit add appropriate color ...

}
```

Here is the sampler class as in Point2D point = Engine.sampler.sample(row,col,x,y);

```
public class JitteredSample extends Sampler{

public JitteredSample(int samples){
    this.samples = samples;
}

public Point2D sample(int row, int col, int x, int y){

    Point2D point = new Point2D();
    Random random = new Random();
    //Create Sample points
    point.x = x-Engine.world.viewplane.width/2+(col+random.nextFloat())/samples;
    point.y = y-Engine.world.viewplane.height/2+(row+random.nextFloat())/samples;
    return point;
}
```

And here is the Projection class where the rays are being created.

```
public class Perspective1 extends Projection {

public Perspective1(){
    eye = new Point3D(Engine.camera.getPosition());
    lookat = new Point3D(Engine.camera.getLookat());
    up = new Vector3D(Engine.camera.getUp());
    up.normalize();
    double fov = Engine.camera.getHorizontal_fov();
    distance = Engine.world.viewplane.height/2/Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov));

    uvw();
}

public Ray createRay(Point2D point){

        Ray ray = new Ray(eye, u.mul(point.x).add(v.mul(point.y).sub(w.mul(-distance))));
        ray.direction.normalize();

        return ray;
}
}
```

[image: Perspective Projection]

Comment: Definitely add some source code to show what you're currently doing. Particularly, how are you transforming your object coordinates to screen coordinates?

Comment: What does **Engine.sampler.sample** look like? // pls include your relevant import statements *.

Comment: What's the frustum's angular spread? What you're seeing is normal for wide (>120 degrees) views, i.e. progressively larger deformation as you near the boundaries.

Comment: My FOV is at 45 degrees.